# Hide sensitive data in request

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

Maybe its a dumb question, but im gonna ask it anyway...

I had to implement a login form with angular 1.6 + java spring boot + security using oauth for backend.

Its done by now, but i've noticed that sensitive data, like username and password are visible when post to server using chrome inspect page under tab Network. Select the request used to send post data and its there. 
[image: IGM here].

I'm using HTTPS, POST to send form.

Is it normal? Is this information secure?

Comment: Your posting to an HTTPS endpoint so the data is encrypted when its in transit.  *You* can see it in the browser because its *your* browser on *your* machine & *you* just typed it in, its safe to trust yourself.

Comment: It is normal.  The information is as secure on the wire as HTTPS can make it, but both sender and receiver can see it.  That's the nature of the beast.